# How to get excel rows one by one in command text using loop?oledb,c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using `oledb` to read excel file and then i am trying to apply some conditions and then save in db, but i just want to read excel row one by one using loop.

```
 var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
 cmd.CommandText = "select * from [الحيازات$]";// want to get this rows using loop so 
 //that only specific row is selected perform opertion blow then i will save in db,but 
//its selecting all rows now

using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
     //LINQ query - when executed will create anonymous objects for each row
     var query = (from DbDataRecord row in rdr
                  select row)
                 .Select(x =>
                           {
                               //dynamic item = new ExpandoObject();
                               Dictionary<string, string> item = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                               for (int i = 0; i < x.FieldCount; i++)
                               {
                                    //code
                               }
                           });
}
```

Comment: You could tell us which condition you want to use. The oledb support normal sql query format. You could use where condition to add some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
private void ReadExcel()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""";


                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
                {
                    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                    using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                        connection.Open();


                        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);


                        if (dataSet != null && dataSet.Tables[0] != null)
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                            {
                                string value = row["EmailColumnName"].ToString();
                          
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle Exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer sir, but its totally different, i want to create modify command like it should be dynamic using loop so that only rows selected one by one, i.e `command.CommandText = "SELECT top 1,2,3  FROM [Sheet1$]";` like dynamic rows selected one by one only selected data